# Finding a subgroup and left cosets of H in $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a=(1234)\in S_4$. Find the subgroup $H = \langle a \rangle$, and  determine the left cosets of H in $S_4$

Comment: Can you tell what kind of subgroup is $\;H\;$ ? And then how many lefts cosets are there?

Comment: This is what I'm unsure of. I don't know what  $\langle a \rangle$ means.

Comment: $\left<a\right>$ means subgroup generated by $a$

Comment: Ah okay, $\langle a \rangle$ is the subgroup consisting of all elements which you can get by multiplying $a$ by itself.

Comment: Could you give me an example in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ consists of all elements which you can get by multiplying $a$ by itself.  In otherwords, it has the elements $\left\{ a, a^2, a^3, \dots, a^{n-1}, e \right\}$, where $n$ is the order of $a$.  In this case, $$a^2 = (1234)(1234) = (13)(24),$$
$$a^3 = a^2a = (13)(24)(1234) = (1432),$$
$$a^4 = a^3a = (1432)(1234) = (1)(2)(3)(4) = e.$$
Thus we have $H = \left\{ (1234), (13)(24), (1432), (1)(2)(3)(4)\right\}.$

Now are you able to figure out the left cosets?

Comment: Are the left cosets singleton subsets e.g (1)(2)(3)(4)?

Comment: No, and from your answer I'm not sure you understand the notation.  $S_4$ is the group whose elements are permutations of four objects.  For example, if I have four objects and swap the first and third.  We could write this permutation in the notation $(13)(2)(4)$ to indicate that $1$ goes to $3$, $3$ goes to $1$, and $2$ and $4$ stay in place.  The $a$ in your problem looks like $(1234)$, which means that it is the permutation which sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, etc.  Then the subgroup $H$ consists of permutations which arise just by applying $a$ repeatedly.  Does this all make sense so far?

Comment: A left coset is a subset of $S_4$ which is obtained by multiplying all elements of $H$ by some other element of $S_4$ which is not in $H$.  For example let $b = (13)(2)(4)$ be the element of $S_4$ from my above comment.  Then the left coset $bH$ consists of the elements $b, ba, ba^2, ba^3$.  You should write all of these out.  Now you should repeat this with other elements of $S_4$ until you get five *different* cosets (meaning five different from $H$).  I think that doing this exercise will teach you a lot about cosets and composing permutations.